# C# Code Project; View Video of Camera with an Overlay (Windows OS)

Tags: c#, windows, camera

I would like to build a Windows Form application that will be able to

---

A.) Show a live feed of a video from a USB connected camera (easy part)

---

B.) Import a AutoCAD Drawing, DWG Extension, onto said video feed (hard part)

I was wondering if people here would know how to achieve part B? Now the file does not need to be a DWG necessarily, but it will need to show a transparent background so the video feed can show through. What is important is the image imported is centered on the camera

Comment: The transparency of the live feed just has to be set to allow the AutoCAD drawing to be seen.

Comment: Right now I am using this webcam C# project to display the camera. What kind of form should I use to overlay the camera display (PictureBox Type) https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library

Comment: Images should be in picture boxes.  You may want to put the controls into  a panel so they move together.   The panel give you the ability to break a form into multiple sections where each section can move independently.